# Store unsaved model instance in session

Tags: python, django, serialization

I'm trying to store several unsaved model entries in the django session. I would like it to work something like this:

```
KEY = "FOOBAR"
def save_entry_to_session(new_entry, session):
    items = deserialize(session.get(KEY))
    items = append(new_entry)
    session.put(KEY, serialize(items))
```

I have looked in to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/ but the DeserializedObject didn't really play along and seemed like unnecessary overhead. Is there a better way to handle this? Pickle or is this unsafe?

Standard use case: save several items one at a time in the session -> save none, one or more items based on user actions.

Comment: If you have to store an unsaved model, there is a good chance that you are going in a wrong direction. Please describe your use case.

Comment: I'm creating invite links (foo.com/invite/sdfawefFJKFE9) and want to pass them along to the view to (among other things) populate a facebook share-button's href. I do not want to save the model entry since it's not certain  the user will use the link. I intend to save the the model entry with an ajax request (foo.com/invite/save/sdfawefFJKFE9).

Comment: why do you need to store the unsaved model instance?  why can't you just create that model instance at the point where you decide it is valid to save it?

Comment: Since i need to pass along a url to the view and only save it if it's actually used.

Comment: My use case is to have the user enter details in a form, and finish all validation, but then move on to another page where they read and accept terms and conditions before saving the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using djangos model serializers, the deserializedObject was no obstacle. Using pickle would, in this instance, have been easier and safe (since it would never parse user submitted data) but I went with the safer choice to avoid risking exposure later.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a new feature since you asked this question, but in Django 1.10 right now I am able to store an unsaved model in the session just by direct assignment, and it comes back out just fine without any extra work. Just `request.session['thing'] = instance` and then later `instance = request.session['thing']`.